# load the original content after removeAll()

Tags: java

I have a simple question.
What I want to know is, is it possible to bring back the original content of a panel after using `foo.removeAll()`, `foo.revalidate()`, `foo.repaint()`?

kind of like refreshing the whole panel just to bring back the original content.

EDIT: I am using net beans.

As requested, here is the initcomponents from netbeans.

```
private void initComponents() {

        pnl_login = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        txtuser = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtpass = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Main_Pane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        desktop = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        pnl_login.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jLabel1.setText("Username");

        jLabel2.setText("Password");

        jButton7.setText("Login");
        jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton8.setText("Exit");
        jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(txtpass)
                        .addComponent(txtuser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 212, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(txtuser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(txtpass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton8)
                    .addComponent(jButton7))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pnl_login.add(jPanel1, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(this.getExtendedState() | this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setUndecorated(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        Main_Pane.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

        desktop.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Nirmala UI", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(22, 52, 255));
        jButton3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Icons/medical91.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("Vital Signs");
        jButton3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton3.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(110, 51));
        jButton3.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Nirmala UI", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(22, 52, 255));
        jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Icons/bed30.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Bed Rest");
        jButton2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton2.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(110, 51));
        jButton2.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jButton2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton2MousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Nirmala UI", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(22, 52, 255));
        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Icons/medical12.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Issue Medicine");
        jButton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(110, 51));
        jButton1.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Nirmala UI", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(22, 52, 255));
        jButton4.setText("Patient Profile");
        jButton4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton4.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton4.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(110, 51));
        jButton4.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jButton4.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton4MousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Nirmala UI", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(22, 52, 255));
        jButton5.setText("Register Patient");
        jButton5.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton5.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton5.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(110, 51));
        jButton5.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jButton5.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton5MousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Nirmala UI", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(22, 52, 255));
        jButton6.setText("Consult Patient");
        jButton6.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton6.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton6.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(110, 51));
        jButton6.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jButton6.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton6MousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton9.setText("Show login");
        jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout desktopLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(desktop);
        desktop.setLayout(desktopLayout);
        desktopLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(desktopLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(desktopLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(desktopLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(desktopLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(389, 389, 389)
                        .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(desktopLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(283, 283, 283)
                .addComponent(jButton9)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        desktopLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(desktopLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(desktopLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(desktopLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(130, 130, 130)
                .addComponent(jButton9)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        desktop.setLayer(jButton3, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        desktop.setLayer(jButton2, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        desktop.setLayer(jButton1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        desktop.setLayer(jButton4, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        desktop.setLayer(jButton5, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        desktop.setLayer(jButton6, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        desktop.setLayer(jButton9, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

        Main_Pane.add(desktop, "card2");

        getContentPane().add(Main_Pane, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }
```

Comment: Yes. Just re-run the code that adds the original content to the panel.

Comment: im my case, Im going to call initcomponents again right? im using netbeans by the way.

Comment: I don't use Netbeans, so I have no idea what code Netbeans generates for their window-builder. If you're not using a window builder just re-run all the `add` calls.

Comment: too bad I'm using one. I tested re-running the initCompnent() - this loads all the contents but it came back blank. thanks for the try though :)

Comment: Please show us more of your code, for example ```initComponent```

Comment: added as per request